Prometheus metrics too sparse to calculate a rate, especially because they come from 40 different pods
I have a grpc API, with 40 pods and loadbalanced via envoy proxy.
I created a custom summary metric, let's call it server_price_predicted. Each server exposes it based on the requests it treated. When I scrape it and rate it as is, everything works fine.
sum(rate(server_price_predicted_total[1h])) / sum(rate(server_price_predicted_count[1h]))

This is the average price predicted accross all pods, for everything. So it's very superficial.
I wanted to have more control on the fields, so I can capture better the price repartition based on things like:

date: the price predicted for the date X in the future
client_group: a group of client, like premium, regular, etc

The problem is that with this fine granularity, I do not have enough points to compute a rate. Rating needs at least 2 points for the same fields, and MOST IMPORTANTLY the field pod (or instance), which means the same pod needs to recompute the same request with those date/client_group. And I have so many dates and other categories that the probability another price update falls on the same pod within a 24 hour window is close to 0.
So since all my price updates are scattered accross different pods, rating a constant value gives 0 and then summing it also gives 0.
If I could sum the summary by pods, then rate it, it would solve my problem. But this is not possible in PromQL.
Here are the solutions I found and tried:

Drop the labels "pod" and "instance" from my metric. It means every pod will overwrite the last metric value with its current summary, so the overall average price will come from the last request we got. Still better than nothing. But sadly prometheus operator does not allow this and all my metrics disappeared.
Use a prometheus federated to group all metrics on 1 prometheus server that will then be scraped by the central prometheus: I won't go into details but this also didn't work because we have the same pod/instance problem.
Move the metrics calculation to the envoy proxy. This is the best solution on paper. My metrics are computed using a gRPC interceptor that reads the input (to get the date, category) and output (to get the price). If I can intercept my gRPC request in the envoy proxy, I would have a single metric for all pods! But it means coding it in LUA or C++ and cloning/rebuilding envoy...
Not rating the metric but using it as is. This will only work when there is a single data point on the pod. Once a second request comes, the server_price_predicted_total counter will increase by that price. It could maybe be solved using a window in the query but it will still be very messy.
Last resort: binning my fields. If instead of having day dates, I group them into months, and also bin all the other categories, I might get more data points per pod to compute the rate.

There are a lot of other potential solutions I didn't explore (like Prometheus push gateway). But I want to keep things as simple as possible. Perhaps the solution is very easy, like using another metric type rather than Summary that doens't require rate?

Solved by converting all metrics to gauges instead. Surely it means every new request will put its price on the last metric value, but since the data is so sparse and the categories veeery distinctive, this shouldn't create a mess.
